# At which temperature does a concentrated aqueous solution of sodium chloride begin to boil?

Tags: experimental-chemistry, boiling-point

We know, solutes dissolved in water increases the boiling point of water. This question is an MCQ. The options are 96,99,100,104 degree Celsius. The correct answer is 96. Why? If the boiling point INCREASES after adding salt then why not 104?

Comment: Have you excluded an error as the option.

Answer (score 2):

The boiling temperature always increases when adding salt into water. It looks as if salt was attracting water molecules and preventing them from quitting the liquid. So that it is necessary to overheat the solution to let water molecules get into the vapor phase. I have often made this measurements in class and always found about $\pu{104°C}$.

Comment: In explaining this phenomenon, the key is not an interaction between solute and solvent but instead the inability of the solute to exit into the vapor phase at this temperature.